(ˈfyːrən) or [ˈfyːʁən], which IPA transcript is correct?
I'm looking up the phoneme transcript of word führen, and I found two results:
IPA: [ˈfyːʁən], from https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%BChren#f%C3%BChren_(Deutsch)
(ˈfyːrən), from https://de.thefreedictionary.com/f%c3%bchren
I'm totally new to German, so which (ʁ or r) is correct? (or more commonly use?)
== edit ==
This question is not about how to pronounce "r" but how to write its phoneme transcript in IPA (or any other format).
When the answer is "both are correct", there is also more to explain:

one pronunciation, but both IPA transcripts are correct
different pronunciations and each pronunciation has one correct IPA transcript, therefore both transcripts are correct.

More specifically, ʁ or r, which is the correct IPA transcript for r

This question is similar to: Pronunciation of 'r' in German. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RHa: This question is interesting and quite distinct from Pronunciation of 'r' in German. It is about the transcription of the phoneme, not about the pronunciation. I do not think it needs to be edited, since both the title and the text highlight this distinction. The reason why the phoneme is often transcribed as r is a principle in phonemic transcriptions to always choose the most common symbol when there is a choice.

They both are, depending on region and individual speaker. Native speakers of German are not typically very good at even telling the difference between different kinds of "r".
In fact, I would usually pronounce this word with a schwa sound in the middle unless I am aiming for very clear pronunciation. I am no expert in IPA, but I think this is [fyːɐ̯n] in IPA.
Many learners of German have questions about the pronunciation of "r"; you can confirm this if you search the /r/German subreddit for pronunciation r. If you look at the answers there, you will find that the answers are very commonly the same: that there is a lot of variation in how to pronounce "r" and there are more important things to focus on.
